# "Lambast" or "lambaste"

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling, transatlantic-differences

I looked up both *lambast* and *lambaste* in several dictionaries, but came up with no conclusions about which one is AE and which BE (if this distinction can ever be made). Moreover, the different spelling entails different pronunciations: *lambast* [læmˈbæst] vs *lambaste* [læmˈbeɪst].

The Macmillan Dictionary s.v. states that this verb is mainly used in journalism, so I suppose that it's a relatively recently-formed word.

Are there any diatopic variations between the two forms? That is, is one  mainly British and the other mainly American?

If there are no such variations, which one is more correct or widespread in terms of pronunciation and spelling?

Comment: I prefer my lamb basted with mint jelly, personally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Oxford English Dictionary lists *lambaste* from the 17th century, then notes *lambust* and *lambast* as alternate spellings dating only from the 18th century.  My American dictionary also has *lambaste*.

Comment: Does it say anything about the origin of the alternate spellings? The Merriam-Webster says that "lambaste" probably comes from "lam" + "baste". Maybe, its variations—"lambast", "lambust"—stem from some sort of false etymology.

Comment: I'd guess the spelling *lambast* comes from using that pronunciation for *lambaste* (for example, you can't tell anything from the word *lambasted*). The etymology is interesting. I'd always wondered where the British Army got "beasting" from.

Comment: The American dictionary shows both pronunciations for *lambaste* and only one pronunciation for *lambast*.

Comment: Thank you. That sounds to me like an exception to the rule that links orthography and pronunciation in English. I'll explain: usually when a two syllable word has a stressed "a" and is written with a mute "e" at the end, the stressed vowel become a diphthong: e.g. "sale", "bathe", "late". On the contrary, when there's no mute "e" at the end of the word, the "a" is pronounced as a pure vowel: e.g. "bath", "sat", "flat". I suppose that the pronunciation of "lambast" influenced that of "lambaste" in this case.

Answer (score -1):

Analysing the nGrams for "lambast" and "lambaste",

The words appear to have gained currency c1900, and competed ever since, with "lambaste" nearly always a step ahead of its shorter cousin.

As of 2000, "lambaste" is trending up while "lambast" has lost a lot of ground in usage.

nGrams show no major difference between BrE and AmE usage.

Comment: You seem to have misstated some of the ngrams results, -1, while correctly stating others of them.

Comment: and down voting was such fun! lol

Comment: No, not at all!  It's a grave and serious responsibility.  :)

Comment: I have no time to discuss that. What were right and what not, in the analysis?

Comment: In American English [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lambast,lambaste&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=5) for *lambast,lambaste* we see *lambaste* well ahead (not just "a step ahead") and *lambast* declining.  More significantly, in British English [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lambast,lambaste&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=6) *lambaste* is behind – not ahead – which is an important difference between BrE and AmE usage.

Comment: Which is what you should've posted. Not idle criticism. Now put them together into an Answer.

Comment: Don't care to; but please feel free to edit your answer accordingly (if you agree, and of course with ngrams links) so I can undownvote and upvote.